# Graphics Server Documentation or User Guide

Tags: graphics, asp-classic

I got a very old `Classic ASP` code which is running on windows server 2003 the code has lines something like `GSDSVR.GSServerProp` and  `GSSERVER.GSServerProp`. After some research I found that this is some kind of Graphic Server Component to generate chats or graphics, but I am unable to find any example on how to use it.

Block of code I have-

```
  Set GSObject("Bar") = Server.CreateObject("GSDSVR.GSServerProp")

  GSObject("Bar").URL = Graphics_URL

  ... more stuff ...

  GSObject("Bar").Height = 291
  GSObject("Bar").ClipGraph = 1

  Tmp_FileName = GSObject("Bar").DrawGraph()
```

The code generates chart(s) based on some data, Now I want to achieve this using .net.

The problem I am facing is I don't know what is happening in code I just know the out of the code.

Can anyone please help me with documentation or few examples for this graphic server component?

Comment: It has to be some ActiveX dll, did you search through the registry to see what dll it is? And do you want to replace this dll as well or does your .Net code need to use the 'old' dll?

Comment: this will not be used in future I guess... I need to convert the old code to new .net code but for that I need the documentaion to understand the old code.

Comment: search your registry to find this dll and with that you can hopefully find documentation or at least the program this activeX dll belongs to...